# 'Run' dialogue doesn't remember its commands across diff windows sessions

Tags: windows-7, jumplist

I'm using Win 7 Ultimate 32bit SP1. My 'Run' dialogue, and jump lists (files names which appear when I bring my pointer onto a program name like MS Excel, in the start menu's top part) and 'Recent Files' list mostly remain empty, or show only those files which were opened only in the current windows session.

I've tried selecting (in fact it was already selected): Start Menu/Task Bar Properties> Start Menu Tab> 'Store and Display a list of recently opened programs'.

I've also checked the relevant policy in GPE.MSC

Can you pls help. All these are posing too many problems. Even those file names get lost who have been pinned permanently in the jump lists.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for no answers!! Since I was able to find the problem. I had inadvertently disabled "Taskband Pin" and perhaps "Start Menu Pin" also in the Yanicsot Context Menu Manager. Don't know how they affected 'Run' dialogue and 'Recent Files' history also, but they did. So thanks!!